# Sending SMS to a list of names, numbers dictionary while also carrying over another key value

Tags: python, twilio

Alright so I have a function that should allow me to send multiple SMS to a list of dictionaries within my script. So for example my list of dictionaries looks like

```
users = [{'User': entry.name.value, 'Number':entry.telephoneNumber.value, 'days':days_left.days}]
```

and I have a function within a class that will send an sms to each phone number in the list of dictionaries, but within each sms it will find and attach the right name, and days left.

```
        def send_sms():
            client = Client(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token)
            for d in users:
                for name, number in d.items():
                    message = client.messages.create(
                        to=number,
                        from_=twilio_from_phone_number,
                        body=f'Hello {name}, you have {days_left.days} days left to reset your password. -IT')
                    print(message.sid)
            self.app.log.info(f'Sent {len(users)} sms msgs to users')
        send_sms()
```

so I am a little stock on the logic within the function. I need to be able to access individual names and days left. For reference:

```
days_left = (pwd_expire_date.astimezone(tz=None) - today)
```

days left = each users password expiration time - todays date(leaving how many days they have left)
This is a script to access AD and check if a users password is within 30,15,3 days and if it is send them SMS and Email notification. This is my first real task as an engineer and it is a little more than I understand. I know my for loop logic isn't right because that just grabs key, value. But how would I iterate through my list of dictionaries and pull out the appropriate values? PS(The body is just an example). I am not sure if you will have a MWE because this is connecting to my AD, but I think my issue is with basic python syntax. Thanks for any help. If this is a dumb question I am sorry.

My expected outcome is :

```
Each user receive a SMS to their specific number, with their name and days till they have to reset their password.

'Hello John, you have 15 days left to reset your password. -IT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your code is mostly right! Your loop through the users, `for d in users:` seems correct to me. At this point you should find that `d` is the dictionary of user data.

I think your issue is the use of `for name, number in d.items():`. Instead of trying to get the data out of an array of tuples that `.items()` returns is going to be hard. Instead, you can access the data from the dictionary directly using square brackets (or the `get` method) and the name of the field, like `d["Username"]`. Try this:

```py
def send_sms():
    client = Client(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token)
    for d in users:
        message = client.messages.create(
            to=d["Number"],
            from_=twilio_from_phone_number,
            body=f'Hello {d["Username"]}, you have {d["days"]} days left to reset your password. -IT')
        print(message.sid)
    self.app.log.info(f'Sent {len(users)} sms msgs to users')

send_sms()
```

Comment: Wow Phil thank you! This makes so much sense now, and seems to have the output I am looking for! I was just looking at the logic wrong.